# ios - Align imageview right after the label

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uilabel

I am trying to align an imageview right after a label. The problem is that the label length can vary so I cant seem to position my image view after that.

---UILabel---ImageView.

Is there a way to align my imageview right after the label's text independent of how long the text is? Is autolayout the right way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `autolaytout` is way to go. Just ctrl click between your UILabel and ImageView and select `Horizontal Spacing` in the menu that popup. That will let you define a fix amount between your two ui elements.

Comment: The problem is that I cant use auto layout as we support iOS5 as well.

Comment: You can use the sizeWithFont method on the string used in your UILabel this will estimate the size of your label. You can then adjust the positioning of your image view accordingly.